Parsing the existing swagger/openapi url
There is an existing swagger/openapi url and the sevice definitions are available and try some tesing there. This service is owned by another team though.
It is a spring application and springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui library is used for genrating this swagger/openapi document.
Is there any library to parse this swagger/openapi url and get few key items like
GET /api/test.json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: application/json, text/javascript

Regards

https://openapi.tools/#parsers
